# how to fix image upload issue in playstore?

Tags: cordova

In desktop image upload option is working when I deploy the same code into play store. The image upload option is not working in mobiles how to fix this issue if anyone knows about this problem please reply

Comment: Could you provide more information, e.g. source code and error codes?

Comment: sir during deployment no errors are there i already deployed after deployed image upload functionality is not working